# Display current song Web API

Tags: php, spotify, spotify-app

I am looking to display the current song I am listening to on Spotify. There is an endpoint to obtain this [here (Spotify Web API Player)](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-the-users-currently-playing-track/) which requires authentication through the Spotify web API.

If I have obtained a Client ID and Client Secret from my app settings, which authentication type is suited to my needs?

I've looked [here (Spotify Authorization Flows)](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#supported-authorization-flows) but from my understanding and confusion, I believe this cannot be done as the request for authentication would be to authenticate the user against my app and display their current song and not mine.

Fundamentally, I'm looking for a way to display my current song without the end user having to request access to my app but instead, the app uses my details.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arielle from Spotify here.

The Authorization Code Flow is what you're looking for, but you are correct that in a standard implementation users would see their own data (which makes sense - you usually don't want users seeing other users' data)

However, you can set it up such that you're the only one who authenticates and only your data is shown. I actually made an app to show *my* currently playing track a little while back. Check it out on Glitch here: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/ari-currently-playing

You can simply start editing the project to "remix" it and make your own version!

Hope this helps, let me know if you run into any issues!

Comment: Hi Arielle, thanks for response. Are you able to elaborate on how I setup so that I am the only one who authenticates? I've read through your example code (I don't know Python so did my best) and I can see that you obtain the code from from the url which you then use to get an access token. How would I get that code as I would still be required to authenticate through oauth before my callback got that code.

Comment: Yes! You will have to authenticate through OAuth *the first time the code runs*, just by loading the app. After that, the token will be cached and then refreshed when it expires, so you stay logged in. The OAuth flow is only shown when there is no token, so your user won't see it or be able to log in :)

If you want to check out how it would work/look, just "Remix" the project and put your client id/secret and redirect URI into `.env`. You should be prompted to authenticate.